# Does NightwatchJS support running tests by tags

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, gui-testing, nightwatch.js

I see that there exists a "tags" support with NightwatchJS , as in

https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/blob/master/examples/tests/github.js#L2

But could not see much documentation about how the "tags" could be used.

Neither in nightwatch --help

Is there a facility to run the tests based on these tags ?

For example,  run all tests with tag "sms" but exclude all with tag "mms" ?

Comment: this question was asked when tags was not supported (https://github.com/beatfactor/nightwatch/issues/186) , it is a standard feature now

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See documentation: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-tags

---

> To select which tags to run, use the --tag command line flag:
>
> `$ nightwatch --tag login`
>
> Specify multiple tags as:
>
> `$ nightwatch --tag login --tag something_else`